# Не могу понять откуда появляется ���

Tags: php, sql

Всем привет, очень странная вещь происходит, впервые сталкиваюсь

```
SELECT * FROM index WHERE kategoriya LIKE '%cafe%'
```

Вот такой запрос строит такую ссылку

```
index.php?brands%5B%5D=%27%cafe%%27
```

И все вроде хорошо, мне выводит все заведения с категорией `cafe`, но как только я перехожу на вторую страницу, то ссылка практически не меняется

```
index.php?brands%5B%5D=%27%cafe%%27&page=2
```

Но вот в запросе часть `'%cafe%'` меняется на `'�fe%'` и мне выводит что в БД ничего не найдено, ну это логично

Но вот понять не могу как такое `'%cafe%'` может поменяться на `'�fe%'` при простом переходе на вторую страницу, но еще страннее это то, что с другими категориями `restaurants, pizzeria` такого не происходит, они работают отлично.

Весь код неоднократно проверял, вроде нигде ошибки нет, все категории одинаково прописаны, а сбой происходит только с `cafe,fast_food`, помогите и объяснить что не так?

Comment: а зачем вы проценты в строку запроса передаёте?

Comment: и кавычки тоже...

Comment: @МихаилРебров это массив

Comment: нет...массив - это %5B%5D, а %27% это кавычка одинарная и процент

Comment: не проще ли передать просто ?brands[]=cafe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если преобразовать `%` в url encode значение то получится `%25`

а  `�`  преобразуется в `%ca`

У вас `%ca` поскольку считаеться encoded то и получаеться `�`.

Поменяйте `%ca` на `%25ca`

`index.php?brands%5B%5D=%27%cafe%%27`

на

`index.php?brands%5B%5D=%27%25cafe%25%27`

Comment: спасибо за ответ, начинаю немного понимать что происходит, но вот почему  с  `'fast_food'  >  '�st_food%'`  и `bars_and_pubs >  '�rs_and_pubs%'` такое происходит? Такую же операцию по замене произвести?

Comment: Я же написал вместо %  -> %25

Comment: да, я это понял, я попробовал и все получилось, спасибо, но вот почему без `% -> %25` другие категории работают отлично, хотелось бы разобраться

Comment: @harbor Тут тоже просто encode по стандарту имеет представление `%`  + 2 символа `0-f`. Т.е. если будет %gg то оно проигнорирует и будет считать процент как процент.

Comment: @harbor И ещё , похоже ваш php код можно атаковать через SQL Injection. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: может вы знаете хорошую статью где описано как защититься от SQL Injection? А вообще я использую функцию `clear_string`, но мне кажется что этого мало

Comment: @clear_string http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp, http://php.net/manual/ru/security.database.sql-injection.php, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php